why its important for a software to do one thing and do it well
actuality what make a software bad if he do most of the things in a system and that software do all its jobs well  why UNIX philosophy prefer to set as stander for its programs should "do one thing and do it well"

Possibly unpopular opinion: That "do one thing and do it well" is a phrase that means anything the person using it wants it to mean when they need a stick to wield in support of their own opinions. (And I could use nastier phrases too.) Putting "philosophy" like that in the driver's seat means putting a lower priority on actually making things work.

i think you try to define the phrase but I ask why its important first of all

And by phrasing it like that, you're assuming everyone accepts it is important in the first place. For some people, it likely is. But in some particular cases, it appears from the outside to be important exactly because it can be used as an argument that is almost automatically accepted.

You will notice that a lot of GNU software actively disregards this philosophy in the name of convenience (but GNU is not Unix, so, shrug) and that things like systemd does not seem to be informed by it. I'm assuming that "Why is it important?" will have mostly a historic significance in terms of the early development of the tools used on Unix systems, in comparison to tools used on other operating systems of the time (or, to some degree, Linux today).

Since systemd was brought up, the flamewars about it are exactly what I was just thinking about. In practice, what Linux systems used before systemd was SysV -style init scripts, and there a few cases where those scripts did not do their thing well. But for some reason, systemd gets commonly bashed for not adhering to the philosophy even though it does the "thing" of managing startup and daemons rather much more "well" than the piles of scripts that were before.

Sure, there are things in systemd that could be done differently, and some things I don't agree with either. But at least as far the "discussions" I've seen are concerned, it appears to me that the mentioned "philosophy" is used as dogma which precludes discussion about the actual technical merits. Or well, at least tries to anyway; most major distributions had the technical discussion too, and did the switch.

@ilkkachu You will notice that I put no judgement about quality or fitness-for-purpose in my comment. My comment was merely an attempt at getting the OP to rephrase the question in a more historical context (possibly "Why was 'the philosophy' special at the time of the birth of Unix?").  I have closed the question until it is modified.  It certainly does not point to any specific piece of software in its current form.

I wonder why some one closed my question i just try to learn some thing from you

@Kusalananda, you're right, you didn't, not explicitly anyway. However, that "do one thing and do it well" is phrased in a way that it seems inherently good, and a direct opposite would seem to include doing things badly... That, and the way it often seems to be taken as some sort of scripture makes it a bit hard to use in a discussion of the merits and issues of different ways of accomplishing some technical goal.

E.g. I think being able to use different tools together is a good thing, but I'm not at all sure it's a good thing if the only way to accomplish something is to create a multi-part pipeline of various tools...

The idea behind this was to have simple. modular software that is flexible and reliable.
It allows the user to put multiple programs together to perform more complex tasks.
Having a big monolith of a program - one thing that does everything, would be quite complex, buggy etc - there are criticisms that some software (e.g systemd and others) actually deviate from this and is too complex and monolithic. I kind of agree with this to some extent - e.g. when its being used as a cron alternative etc - but you cant please everyone, simple to some people can mean complex to others.
